# im using VSCODE gnucobol, why its not accepting decimal in accept statement?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Im using VSCode (WSL-UBUNTU) , why im not able to input decimal in accept command. Example to enter 55.50, decimal point is not accepted by the program.

```
   identification division.
   program-id . "numeric".
   author.
   environment division.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   77 WAITING PIC X.
 
   01 num1 pic 9(5).99 .
   screen section.
   01 CLEAR-SCREEN.
       02 BLANK SCREEN. 
   procedure division.
       perform proc-numeric.
       STOP RUN.
   proc-numeric.
       DISPLAY  "NUM 1 : " LINE 5 COL 1 
       ACCEPT NUM1 LINE 5 COL 20 background-color 2.

       display "num1: " line 9 col 1
       DISPLAY NUM1  LINE 9 COL 40.    
       accept waiting LINE 20 COL 4.
```

Comment: A picture of `9(5).99` implies that the input is `00055.50`.  I think you need a picture of `Z(3)99.99` or `Z(4)9.99`.

Comment: That's not vscode specific, only GnuCOBOL specific... I haven't checked but you may want to try `pic9(5)v99` - or just accept `PIC X` then convert the result with `FUNCTION NUMVAL`.
See https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/cobol/thread/aaf67cb9d2/ for note about how numeric accept does (not) work with GnuCOBOL currently.